# how to solve java.awt.event.ActionListener does not throw IOException error?

Tags: java, actionlistener, ioexception

I am trying to make that when my button "SaveImage " clicks it save my data into the given file name. when I try to run my `save(PrintWriter write)`into ActionListener it shows an error.

My stacktrace

```
actionPerformed (java.awt.event. ActionEvent) in
Oval.SaveButtonAction Cannot implement
actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent) in
java.awt.event.ActionListener
overridden method does not throw java.io.IOException
```

this is my code.

```
public class Oval extends JPanel 
{


 private String filename = "";
    private PrintWriter writer;

public Oval() throws IOException
    {
        Buttons();      

    }

public void save(PrintWriter writer) throws IOException // this is my save method....
    {

        for(int i=0;i<ovalColor.size();i++)
        {
            writer.println(ovalX.get(i)+","+ovalY.get(i)+","+ovalColor.get(i).getRGB());
        }
    }

String filename  = "123.txt"
writer = new PrintWriter(filename);

/**
     * Action Listener for saveImage button
     */
class SaveButtonAction implements ActionListener  
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) throws IOException // here i am getting Exception error
        {
            save(writer);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're getting an `IOException` on a class declaration (not possible)? Or in the `save()` method? You need to post a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. Also, include your entire stacktrace.

Comment: i am getting error at `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) `

Comment: If you had followed my advice (:P) and posted the full stacktrace, I guarantee you'd see it lead to your `save()` method...and then to the `writer.println()` method. I suggest you do some research on how to use your IDE's debugger tool and watch what happens when you run the program.

Comment: I added my stacktrace. I am using BlueJ and i know how to debug the perogramme but my programe is not compiling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your class `SaveButtonAction` you implement the `actionPerformed` method as this is defined in the `ActionListener` interface.

If you check the source code, you'll see that `ActionListener#actionPerformed` does not throw any kind of exception in it's signature. Yet when you implement it you perform a call to `Oval#save` which throws the `IOException`. When attempting to do so, you add a `throws` clause in the method's signature thus altering it.

This effectively breaks the contract defined by the interface and leads to the error mentioned in your question.

Either lose the `throws` clause and handle the exception internally, or if you're so interested in it wrap it in an unchecked exception and re-throw it.

I would also strongly advise on reading up on the proper way of implementing interfaces. It seems that you're lacking in that area.